# How do I best list multiple positions at a single company?

Tags: support, jobs

Right now a Careers Profile only gives you one line for a Job Title, however I am wanting to list both my previous and current titles for that position.  For example, my previous title was "Senior Web Developer" but now my title is "Software Development Manager".  I really want to have both on there somehow to show that I'm not just a non-technical manager but I have actual experience building systems (and even though I'm a manager I still end up spending 50% of my time coding or doing architecture design that gets worked on by others on my team).

I would like to reflect that I rose up to development manager through excelling at being the senior developer but the Careers 2.0 profile doesn't seem to have an obvious way to accomplish this.

So does anyone have any good tips for listing multiple job titles at a single job?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, I was mroe trying to figure out how this should be done on StackExchange's Career site.  I have ideas on how to do it on a formal resume, but careers has a rigid structure

Comment: Why did you delete this?

Comment: Don't remember, it was late.  I think I just figured I would reword it to prevent more workplace.stackexchange only redirections/downvotes

Comment: That's a good question, luckily Mr. @Juice here somehow found it and undeleted. :)

Comment: It's pretty easy to undelete when your a mod!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to create two separate Experience entries, or a single one and explain the promotion(s) in the Responsibilities field.  If I had to choose one, I would do two entries.